# Code sample exits during call to shed_col() without giving an error message

Tags: armadillo

The sample code shown below exits when calling shed_col() without giving an error message.  It does not continue to the next line in the source code (not shown).  I am trying to remove the last column.  The problem is in Mat_meat.hpp at line 4394 when calling steal_mem(X).

The file size where inDataVoidPtr is read is 2101248 bytes

```
int32_t m = 1024;
int32_t n = 513;
int16_t* dataPtr = static_cast<int16_t*>(inDataVoidPtr);
arma::Mat<int16_t> intMat(dataPtr, 2, m*n, false, true);
arma::fmat floatMat = arma::conv_to<arma::fmat>::from(intMat);
arma::cx_fmat complexMat((std::complex<float>*)floatMat.memptr(), m, n, false, true);
complexMat.shed_col(n-1);
```